# Automatic slideshow on homepage only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am developing a website that automatically starts a javascript slideshow on the opening page (which is always the homepage). However, when you click in the menu on 'home' which refers to the same page, the slideshow starts again which is not what I want.

Does anyone know javascript that can fix this problem?

Tom

Answer (score 4):

You can set a [cookie in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) and then check if the cookie is present when reloading the page. There is also a referal variable in JS: `document.referrer`, you can use a simple `if` statement to compair the value with the homepages URL.

If you are using ASP or PHP you can use the referral URL to see if the user has come from your website.

Comment: I thought about this, but what if someone visits this page twice a day, the slideshow should start twice as well. How long should it be before the cookie expires?

Comment: You can work out the average time someone spends on your website, or perhaps use `document.referrer` to compair the referral URL if you want to keep it all in JS.

Comment: Use a session cookie, which lasts only as long as the user is on your website, then is deleted automatically. I use the jQuery "cookies" plug-in (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)